# Установка асинхронно загруженной картинки в css background

Tags: javascript

Цель: асинхронно загрузить иображение и запихнуть его как исходное для background элемента. Исходные данные:

```js
var image = document.images[0];
var downloadingImage = new Image();
downloadingImage.onload = function(){
  // set sourc as css ?? 
        // = this.src;
};
downloadingImage.src = "/images/login/12.JPG";
```

```css
<style>
    .login-layout-transparent {
        background: url(images/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;
</style>
```

Comment: Разве ресурсы не асинхронно грузятся? Для асинхрона `setTimeout(function() { element.style.background = 'url(images/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;'}, 0);`

Comment: @Doofy, грузятся асинхронно, поэтому фоновая картинка появляется слоями. Перегонять всё(а вариантов фона много) в прогрессивный jpeg  проблематично. Поэтому хочется выводить фоновое изображение после полной его загрузки. Ваш вариант со временем на крайний случай, т.к. не зависит от того, была ли загружена картинка

Comment: Ну так если слоями, вон же скрипт асинхронный в вопросе `image.onload = ...` Сначало src, скрыть элемент, по onload показать

Comment: @Doofy, можете дать ответ с полным кодом? В моём понимании если я внутрь асихронного запроса запихну `url(images/loading.gif) 50% no-repeat;` он ровно также будет её по-прежнему пытаться скачать слоями..

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, нет, если внутри onload установить в качестве `background-image` урл загруженной картинке, изображение скорее всего возьмется из кэша

Comment: *"Перегонять всё(а вариантов фона много) в прогрессивный jpeg проблематично."* Лучше найдите способ перегнать все картинки автоматически.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, искал, была даже идея один онлайн сервис раздебажить и попользоваться их апи.. Адекватных способов сделать автоматически не нашёл

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) не смотрели?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, пакетно не умеет(я не смог научить).

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko такие вещи, как `cmd.exe`, `powershell` (windows) или `bash` (linux) тоже не смотрели? :)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko обычная обработка превращается в пакетную просто добавлением цикла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из настроек стилей вытаскиваем `src` изображения, создаём новое через *JS*, присваиваем ему этот `src` и по загрузке вставляем в блок, а у самого блока убираем `background`

```html
<div class='img' background='none'></div>
```

```css
.img { background: url(img.jpg); }
```

```js
img = new Image();

image = document.querySelector('.img');
style = window.getComputedStyle(image);
img.src = style.backgroundImage.slice(5, -2);
image.style.background = 'none';

img.onload = function() {
    image.appendChild(img);
    // image.outerHTML = img.outerHTML; // Если блок не нужен, заменяем его изображением
}
```

Comment: Либо в js `image.style.background = 'none';`, либо сразу в html `background='none'`